# Magento 2.3.4 Category Image loading from /pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/

Tags: magento2.3

We just found that all categories images are loading from `/pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/` instead of `/pub/media/catalog/category/` directory in Magento 2.3.4 latest version.

Does anyone know why category loading from temp folder?

Is this permission issue or bug in Magento 2.3.4?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Edit:
Found that, it's default Magento issue in version 2.3.4

Comment: Facing same issue. The category image `image1.jpg` should ideally be uploaded as `pub/media/catalog/category/i/m/image1.jpg` but it is uploaded *directly* in `pub/media/catalog/tmp/category` and stays there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the images being sent to the "tmp" folder with Magento 2.3.4.

I was also getting the error **"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."** 
Not sure if you were receiving this error as well.

It turned out to be a "Mod Security" issue with my server. I called the hosting company and had them perform a 'Tail Watch' while I added a category image and a category thumbnail image. They then white-listed the process and my IP and all was good to go.

Comment: Happy to hear that all was good with your website. So now images are stored and saved in pub/media/catalog/tmp/category directory or in pub/media/catalog/ ?

Comment: They are now stored in pub/media/catalog/category/. Not the tmp folder anymore.